# Getx in not updating value in navigation rails flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

I am using Obx in the navigation rails and updating the text widget. When I tap on the **filter by source** widget and select some values it does not update the length/count but when I tap on the **filter by country** widget the **filter by a source** shows the count. Same for the widget **filter by country**. It does not update the value in real-time. This is my rails widget

```
 NavigationRail(
    selectedIndex: homeController.rails.value,
    onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
      homeController.rails.value = index;
    },
    labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
    destinations: <NavigationRailDestination>[
      const NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt_sharp),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.list_alt),
        label: Text('Layouts'),
      ),
      const NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.language_outlined),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.language),
        label: Text('Filter by language'),
      ),
      NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.source_outlined),
          selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.source),
          label: Obx(() => Text(
              'Filter by source ${homeController.filterSources.value.length}'))),
      NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.earthAsia),
          selectedIcon:
              const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.earthAsia),
          label: Obx(
            () => Text(
                'Filter by country ${homeController.filterCountry.value.length}'),
          )),
    ],
  ),
```

This is my get controller

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var filterCountry = [].obs;
  var filterSources = [].obs;


  void filterCountryFunc(String e) {
    if (filterCountry.value.contains(e)) {
      filterCountry.value.remove(e);
    } else {
      filterCountry.value.add(e);
    }
    update();
  }

  void filterSourcesFunc(String e) {
    if (filterSources.value.contains(e)) {
      filterSources.value.remove(e);
    } else {
      filterSources.value.add(e);
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

This is my complete dart stateful class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:newsconnects/constants.dart';
import 'package:newsconnects/controllers/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:newsconnects/controllers/sources_controller.dart';
import 'package:newsconnects/translations/helper.dart';
import 'package:newsconnects/views/widgets/custom_checkBoxTile.dart';

import 'news_view.dart';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController controller;
  late final List<String> _syncChannels = [];
  HomeController homeController = Get.put(HomeController());
  SourcesController sourcesController = Get.find<SourcesController>();

  final List _screens = <Widget>[
    const NewsView(),
    Center(
      child: Text(t.getText('notifications')),
    ),
    const Center(
      child: Text('Politics'),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();

    print('Home');

    _resources();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 75.0,
        leadingWidth: 90,
        leading: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.refresh,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () => _showModelSheet(context),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.add_box_sharp,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
              const Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
            ]),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Center(
          child: Text('NewsConnect'),
        ),
        actions: [
          const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Options',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert))
        ],
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(30.0),
          child: TabBar(
              controller: controller,
              isScrollable: true,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: const [
                Tab(
                  child: Text('All News'),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('Notifications'),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('Politics'),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[..._screens],
      ),
    );
  }

  _showModelSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
        ),
        builder: (context) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 400.0,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10.0))),
              child: Obx(
                () => Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          NavigationRail(
                            selectedIndex: homeController.rails.value,
                            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                              homeController.rails.value = index;
                            },
                            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
                            destinations: <NavigationRailDestination>[
                              const NavigationRailDestination(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt_sharp),
                                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.list_alt),
                                label: Text('Layouts'),
                              ),
                              const NavigationRailDestination(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.language_outlined),
                                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.language),
                                label: Text('Filter by language'),
                              ),
                              NavigationRailDestination(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.source_outlined),
                                  selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.source),
                                  label: Obx(() => Text(
                                      'Filter by source ${homeController.filterSources.value.length}'))),
                              NavigationRailDestination(
                                  icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.earthAsia),
                                  selectedIcon:
                                      const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.earthAsia),
                                  label: Obx(
                                    () => Text(
                                        'Filter by country ${homeController.filterCountry.value.length}'),
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
                          // This is the main content.
                          Expanded(
                              child: IndexedStack(
                            index: homeController.rails.value,
                            children: [
                              _layouts(),
                              _language(),
                              _sources(),
                              _country(),
                            ],
                          ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Divider(thickness: 1, height: 1),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              homeController.filterSources.value.clear();
                              homeController.filterCountry.value.clear();
                            },
                            child: const Text('CLEAR All')),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('APPLY'))
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _myRadioButton({required String title, required int index}) {
    return GetBuilder<HomeController>(
      builder: (_) => RadioListTile(
        value: homeController.layout[index],
        groupValue: homeController.isGrid.value,
        onChanged: (newValue) =>
            homeController.onClickRadioButton(int.parse(newValue.toString())),
        title: Text(title),
        activeColor: Consts.appMainColor,
      ),
    );
  }

  _layouts() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        _myRadioButton(
          title: "List View",
          index: 0,
        ),
        _myRadioButton(
          title: "Grid View",
          index: 1,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _language() {
    return Obx(
      () => Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          CustomCheckBoxListTile(
              value: homeController.isEnglish.value,
              title: const Text('English'),
              onTap: (newVal) {
                homeController.isEnglish.value = newVal ?? false;
              }),
          CustomCheckBoxListTile(
              value: homeController.isArabic.value,
              title: const Text('Arabic'),
              onTap: (newVal) {
                homeController.isArabic.value = newVal ?? false;
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _sources() {
    return GetBuilder<HomeController>(builder: (_) {
      return ListView(
          children: _syncChannels
              .map((e) => CustomCheckBoxListTile(
                  value: homeController.filterSources.value.contains(e),
                  title: Text(e),
                  onTap: (newVal) {
                    homeController.filterSourcesFunc(e);
                  }))
              .toList());
    });
  }

  _country() {
    return GetBuilder<HomeController>(
        builder: (_) => ListView(
            children: sourcesController.mapSelectedChannelCheckList.keys
                .map((e) => CustomCheckBoxListTile(
                    value: homeController.filterCountry.value.contains(e),
                    title: Text(e.toString()),
                    onTap: (newVal) {
                      homeController.filterCountryFunc(e);
                    }))
                .toList()));
  }

  void _resources() {
    List.generate(
        sourcesController.mapSelectedChannelCheckList.values.length,
        (index0) => List.generate(
            sourcesController.mapSelectedChannelCheckList.values
                .elementAt(index0)
                .length,
            (index1) => List.generate(
                sourcesController.mapSelectedChannelCheckList.values
                    .elementAt(index0)
                    .elementAt(index1)
                    .values
                    .length,
                (index2) => List.generate(
                    sourcesController.mapSelectedChannelCheckList.values
                        .elementAt(index0)
                        .elementAt(index1)
                        .values
                        .elementAt(index2)['channels']
                        .length,
                    (index3) => _syncChannels.add(sourcesController
                        .mapSelectedChannelCheckList.values
                        .elementAt(index0)
                        .elementAt(index1)
                        .values
                        .elementAt(index2)['channels'][index3]
                        .keys
                        .toString())))));
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like there is nothing wrong with the given code. Would you please [edit] the question and copy-paste the full class where `NavigationRail` is built?

Comment: I have updated the question please review it